# I changed /phpmyadmin/ to something different and now when I try to login the index.php doesn't work

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I am currently having issues. So, I access my phpmyadmin so `http://www.(IP).com/` (I changed the directory to something else)

When I go to that page I get the login screen.

But when I try and login comes up with this [error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKdwI.png)

Comment: Can you see something in the logs? Defaults are in `/var/log/apache2/`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the directory back to what it was originally.  The error you are seeing is just the beginning.  You can't login because the system can't find the installed files.  The installed directory doesn't exist if you have changed the directory name.

If you want to access the phpadmin browser by a different link you would have to configure this by modifying the `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` file.

The `phpmyadmin` part of `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` is an alias.  You can alias that to any name you wish.  Use this to make a change.

The `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Change from:

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin


    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Change to:

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /mysecrettool /usr/share/phpmyadmin


    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Now you can bring up Phpmyadmin with `http://localhost/mysecrettool`.  The `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` would fail.

Comment: You missed the 'my' in your first path.

Comment: @JakobLenfers Can you advise if you are still having the problem.  It was my intentions to tell you what to edit.  Did you find the file?  Hopefully by writing it twice I was able to help you to get it working.  If you are still having an issue I'll stay at the drawing board until I can help you get it resolved.  Look at the two `change from` and `change to` items and let us know if it works or fails.

Comment: This wasn't my question, I just wanted to point out your typo since I couldn't suggest an edit with only two new characters

Comment: I understand the question and the typo which I resolved.  I was hoping to know if you are still having an issue.  I keep question where I'm trying to help a user marked until the issue is resolved.  Then I move on to other questions from other users.  I was just wondering did the answer resolve your issue.  If so I'm going to remove it from my local support queue.

Comment: Again, I didn't ask the question

Comment: @JakobLenfers My mistake.  Thanks again for the typo correction!